# get tAda for cardano legacy testnet

Tags: testnet, faucet

How can I get testnet ada for cardano testnet, Now that [cardano faucet](https://docs.cardano.org/cardano-testnet/tools/faucet) only has option to get tAda for preprod or preview testnet. I'm trying to mint NFT using this website. https://stage.cardahub.io/marketplace My nami wallet address addr_test1qppc30u4xqy3afe0vlpg65p850w88zw8zxa066r5rs980ltxfzqvxhdf33fnyepwwkhuua522lvyaajyk3l5lp7204kscn3pax Please send me 20 tAda if you have some.

Answer (score 0):

The `testnet` is deprecated, latest release of node does not support it. Best to use `pre-prod`.

Comment: Yes I know its deprecated, I tried to use the above website mentioned in my question. I guess I'll just skip that. BTW do you know any testnet NFT marketplace.